# Prepositional phrase

Tags: phrases

There are two sentences :

1. We found it in our kitchen.
2. The storm came quickly out of the south.

"in our kitchen" and " out of the south" are prepositional phrases,right?
I was told, that prepositional phrases are prepositions and nouns /pronouns they reffer to. But in the first sentence it is not just a preposition and noun, it is preposition, pronoun and noun, that's why I think it can be something else.
In the second sentence, there is " out", which can be both adverb and preposition, of, which is the preposition and the noun "south", I dont know, whether" out of the south" is a prepositional phrase, it is confusing.

Comment: A prepositional phrase is a preposition and a **Noun Phrase** as its object. Noun phrases can have nouns in them, but they also have adjectives, articles. quantifiers, and relative clauses. So whoever told you it was only a noun didn't tell you all of it. Or maybe you missed something.

Comment: See also https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/prepositional-phrases.4032847/

Answer (score 2):

"In" and "out of" are here prepositions followed by *noun phrases,* which may or may not be individual nouns. "Our kitchen" and "the south" are both noun phrases.

Comment: +1 and "our" isn't a pronoun, but a possessive adjective.

Comment: @gotube It depends on your preferred terminology; I would classify it as a pronoun serving as a determiner. If it were a true adjective, you could say "the our kitchen" or "an our kitchen." Instead, "our" serves the same syntactic function as an article.